# How to install Python?

Tags: software-installation, python

I downloaded a version of Python because I would like to program in the language, but I have no idea how to actually download it. There are many files in the download folder, but I have no idea what to do with them. Can someone walk me through a step-by-step process?

Apologies, I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: why? python is an integral part of any Ubuntu version. Just type "python"  on commandline

Comment: Python is built into Ubuntu. It is used for many of the system tasks. Downloading and installing a different version of python will almost certainly break Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu already comes with Python. Still if you want to install python in Ubuntu then use command

`sudo apt install python3` or `sudo apt-get install python3.6`